# Locating a record based on two datetime column in Laravel 6

Tags: sql, laravel

I need to get a record based on a datetime range (between start and end). This is really an appointment that Ive book between 09:00 and 12:30 (today) (using 24hr).

I've booked another appointment for (8:00 or 9:00) to 10:30 (today). I need to find that appointment where 10:30 clashes with another appointment of that same day. How to achieve this with Laravel 6?

Already in database a record for 09:00 to 12:30.

```php
// Columns StartDate and EndDate are both in this format
$newAppointmentDateTime = date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", strtotime("10:30"));
```

```php
$appointment = DB::table('appointment')
  ->where('EndDate', '<=', $newAppointmentDateTime)
  ->where('StartDate', '>=', $newAppointmentDateTime)
  ->first();
```

I'd expect to get a record for the incoming `10:30` as it's between `09:30 and 12:30` of another appointment. Do I need a custom query for this as in to use `whereRaw`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$startTime = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d 9:30');
$endTime = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d 12:30');
$appointment = DB::table('appointment')
        ->where('EndDate', '<=', $endTime)
        ->where('StartDate', '>=', $startTime)
        ->first();
```